# join statement in db2 table

Tags: sql, join, db2, key

I have two tables with ID and date columns. ID and date are the key in both tables. The values are such that, for example, an ID with 15 different dates is stored. How can I use the join statemnet to find IDs that are same in two tables but the date of ID in the first table is not in the second table with same ID?

first table values are

```
0001 1990 
0001 1991
0001 1992
0001 1993
0002 1990
```

and second table values are

```
0001 1990  
0001 1991  
0001 1992  
0001 1993  
0001 1994  
0001 1995  
0002 1990
0002 1991
```

I want join statement returns

```
0001 1994 
0001 1995
0002 1991
```

Comment: Adding your sample data would be helpful

Comment: Your sample data seems to have the dates confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
I've added a couple of values to the 1-st table just for demo.
If you want to exclude ID = '0003' from the result, because there are no such IDs in T2 at all, then uncomment the commended out block.

```
WITH 
  T1 (ID, DATE) AS
(
VALUES
  ('0001', 1990)
, ('0001', 1991)
, ('0001', 1992)
, ('0001', 1993)
, ('0002', 1990)

, ('0002', 2000) -- not exists in T1
, ('0003', 2000) -- ID doesn't exist in T1
)
, T2 (ID, DATE) AS
(
VALUES
  ('0001', 1990)
, ('0001', 1991)
, ('0001', 1992)
, ('0001', 1993)
, ('0001', 1994)
, ('0001', 1995)
, ('0002', 1990)
, ('0002', 1991)
)
SELECT 
  COALESCE (T1.ID, T2.ID)     AS ID 
, COALESCE (T1.DATE, T2.DATE) AS DATE  
FROM T1
FULL JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.DATE = T1.DATE
/*
JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID 
FROM T1 
JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
) I ON I.ID = COALESCE (T1.ID, T2.ID)
*/ 
WHERE T1.ID IS NULL OR T2.ID IS NULL;
```

There result is:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1995 |
| 0002 | 1991 |
| 0001 | 1994 |
| 0002 | 2000 |
| 0003 | 2000 |

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the join statemnet to find IDs that are same in two tables but the date of ID in the first table is not in the second table with same ID?

This is perhaps simpler using `not exists`.  For rows in `table1` that are not in `table2`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.date = t.date);
```

If you want to insist that the ids are in both tables, another `exists` solves that:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.date = t.date) and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

Note:  This answer is based on your question.   Your sample data seems to have the tables in the opposite roles.

Answer (score 0):

Following the data in your example and in order to get the same results, you should query data in the second table that is in the first one based on the id and that differs in the date.

Below is a query that returns the data as per your example.

```
WITH 
  T1 (ID, DATEYEAR) AS
(
VALUES
  ('0001', 1990)
, ('0001', 1991)
, ('0001', 1992)
, ('0001', 1993)
, ('0002', 1990)
)
, T2 (ID, DATEYEAR) AS
(
VALUES
  ('0001', 1990)
, ('0001', 1991)
, ('0001', 1992)
, ('0001', 1993)
, ('0001', 1994)
, ('0001', 1995)
, ('0002', 1990)
, ('0002', 1991)
)
SELECT T2.ID, T2.DATEYEAR
FROM T2
WHERE T2.DATEYEAR NOT IN ( SELECT T1.DATEYEAR FROM T1 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID);
```